# The best way to implement UIPageViewController with both horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Hello in our app we have main menu with for buttons, each opens new view controller modally from left, top , right or bottom depending on position (example below). I want to improve the functionality by using pageviewcontrller instead of modal presentation. Can you give an advise how to implement it in best way?

[image]

Comment: try using collectionview with pagination enable

Comment: you may wanna try ContainerController placed in scrollView or in usual view combined with transition animation between them -- all you need is just define dependency between controllers and pages